# Can I stop a service with some parameters in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm able to put an extra information to an intent for the stopService method.
But how can I read this info from a service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that, the intent isn't delivered to the service. However, you could provide an entry in your service which is used to ask the service to stop itself (along with the extra information you want the service to be aware of).